# « [...] mais il faut une passation » : laquelle, emploi, synonyme ?

Tags: sens, expressions, locutions, suffixes, professions

Dans un article on discute d'un film sur un médecin à la campagne, longuement établi, et qui a de la difficulté à céder sa place à une collègue un peu plus jeune, et on dit :

> Il se croyait irremplaçable, et il l'est un peu, surtout auprès des
>   personnes âgées qu'il suit depuis des lustres, mais il faut une
>   passation. ([*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/cinema/critiques/201612/16/01-5052043-medecin-de-campagne-un-film-qui-guerit-12.php), Chantal Guy).

Le terme [passation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passation) est dérivé du sens juridique du verbe [*passer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passer/1) (surtout l'*acte* etc.<sup>1</sup>) au 15<sup>e</sup>, mais l'expression substantivée [*passation des pouvoirs*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/passation/58459/locution), « l'acte solennel par lequel une autorité parvenue en fin de mandat ou démissionnaire reçoit celle qui lui succède, lui transmet les compétences et se retire » (Larousse), essentiellement leur *transmission*, n'est que du 20<sup>e</sup> (DHLF/Rey). Par ailleurs on a des exemples comme la *[relève](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rel%C3%A8ve/67882?q=rel%C3%A8ve#67131) des générations*, et des syntagmes comme *assurer/prendre la [relève](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rel%C3%A8ve)* (surtout le contexte militaire), et par métonymie des emplois pour ceux qui prennent la relève ou le relais.

---

- Quand on dit qu'il faut une *passation* dans l'article, est-ce d'une *passation des
  pouvoirs* dont on parle, d'une métaphore, d'une extension usuelle pour la simple *transmission*, ou davantage de l'objet de ce qu'on passe ou de comment on passe ; est-ce courant ?
- L'emploi du mot *passation* s'étend-il à tout type de transfert,
  dans tous les domaines, entre deux personnes ; ou est-ce tributaire ici de la particularité de la profession, du contexte de l'exercice de cette profession en région/province, ou d'une particularité administrative (de notoriété publique) dans un tel contexte en France ?
- Peut-on donner un synonyme usuel pour passation en contexte ; la relève est-elle assurée quand il y a passation ; généralement, comment explique-t-on la différence entre un radical verbal doublé d'un suffixe en *-a[tion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-tion)* pour une *action ou le résultat de cette action* (TLFi) et une locution verbale basée sur un radical dont le sens est similaire ou identique comme dans *assurer le fait qu'on passe* ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On a dans le vocabulaire juridique au Québec l'*action en passation de titre*, pour obtenir un jugement (valant titre) suite au [défaut](http://ccq.lexum.com/w/ccq/fr#!fragment/art1712) de passer le titre de propriété (compléter la vente) du promettant-vendeur/acheteur.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Quand on dit qu'il faut une passation dans l'article, est-ce d'une
  passation des pouvoirs dont on parle, d'une métaphore, d'une
  extension usuelle pour la simple transmission, ou davantage de
  l'objet de ce qu'on passe ou de comment on passe ; est-ce courant ?

Il s'agit d'une extension usuelle de "passation de pouvoirs", avec une connotation un peu ronflante. C'est très courant.

- L'emploi du mot passation s'étend-il à tout type de transfert, dans
  tous les domaines, entre deux personnes ; ou est-ce tributaire ici de
  la particularité de la profession, du contexte de l'exercice de cette
  profession en région/province, ou d'une particularité administrative
  (de notoriété publique) dans un tel contexte en France ?

Cette extension usuelle est tout à fait généralisable et généralisée, mais comme dit précédemment, elle comporte une dimension solennelle, qui devrait la faire employer plus particulièrement dans le cadre d'une profession *importante*, ou au contraire d'une activité qui a peu d'importance de manière ironique ou sarcastique. Dans le cadre présent, il s'agit du fait que la profession de médecin de campagne est particulièrement considérée. En effet, un médecin fait partie des notables à la campagne.

- Peut-on donner un synonyme usuel pour passation en contexte ; la
  relève est-elle assurée quand il y a passation ; généralement,
  comment explique-t-on la différence entre un radical verbal doublé
  d'un suffixe en -ation pour une action ou le résultat de cette action
  (TLFi) et une locution verbale basée sur un radical dont le sens est
  similaire ou identique comme dans assurer le fait qu'on passe ?

En contexte: succession, transmission, transition, (succession évoque un certain formalisme, ce qui rapproche particulièrement son sens de passation). Substantif.